# How to use $scope.eval() in angularjs to set $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eval, dynamic-variables

I'm trying to figure out how eval() works in AngularJS, but I can't seem get my head around it.

I have the following:

```
$scope.salaryRate, $scope.priceRate = {
    number: undefined,
    type: undefined,
    from: undefined,
    to: undefined,
    rate: undefined
}

$scope.addRate = function (variable) {
    eval('$scope.' + variable).push({
        'number': eval('$scope.' + variable + 'Rate').number,
        'type': eval('$scope.' + variable + 'Rate').type,
        'days': {
        'days': eval('$scope.' + variable + 'SelectedDay'),
        'daynames': displayDayNames($scope.dayNames, eval('$scope.' + variable + 'SelectedDay'))},
         'from': eval('$scope.' + variable + 'Rate').from,
         'to': eval('$scope.' + variable + 'Rate').to,
         'rate': eval('$scope.' + variable + 'Rate').rate,
         'id': eval(variable + 'Number')
    });
    eval('$scope.' + variable + 'Rate') = {
        number: undefined,
        type: undefined,
        from: undefined,
        to: undefined,
        rate: undefined
    };
}
```

For some reason eval works fine when I am pushing values to a variable array. However for some reason `eval('$scope.' + variable + 'Rate') =` doesnt work and I get the error `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.
I am trying to make my function dynamic, so that I can use it for more than one `$scope`. How do I solve this with AngularJS?

It also happens to fail at this point

```
function findRowIndex(variable, id){
    eval('var ' + variable + 'Rows') = eval('$scope.' + variable);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using eval?  Not a good idea.

Comment: Why on earth are you doing this?

Comment: @Phix, How else would I make a dynamic function where I can input the scope name into the function and modify the scope with the given variable name? The idea is that I have multiple $scope arrays which uses the same functions, which is add, which are exactly the same, besides the variable names.

Comment: @Pytth As I said, I am trying to avoid using two exactly similar functions that do exactly the same, just on different sets of $scope variables.

Comment: As written above, using eval is not a good idea (To say the least). Just pass an object to the function and change it, or return a fresh object and save it to another variable, I've never seen this type of approach. This code is not the right way

Comment: @AlonEitan Do you have an example on how I could do this? I'm really new to AngularJS and still trying to understand how to extract scope information dynamically and reset them.

Comment: If you want to share logic between different 'scopes' then you would create a service to perform that logic. Inject it into your controllers/directives etc b

Comment: @PhyCoMath I tried to write an answer, but because there's not enough information in your question then I can't post it. I can't understand what exactly is `eval('$scope.' + variable + 'SelectedDay')`? Do you have it your controller `$scope.salarySelectedDay` and `$scope.priceSelectedDay`?

Comment: @Alon Eitan, yes, Its an array `[false,false,false,false]` which is set to true whenever a user selects a day.

Comment: @PhyCoMath I see that you already have an answer, so good for you :) Good luck

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks, quite a lot of new things to learn in Angular so good to get some nice help here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)? https://jsfiddle.net/duoxoq8j/2/

```
$scope.addRate = function (variable) {
    $scope[variable].push({
        ...
    });
    $scope[variable + "Rate"] = {
        number: undefined,
        type: undefined,
        from: undefined,
        to: undefined,
        rate: undefined
    };
}
```

This is just basic javascript functionality and has nothing to do with Angular or scopes in particular.

Comment: Do I have to change my $scopes aswell for this? I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [` when I changed my scopes. I didnt even know this existed...

Comment: Check out the fiddle for an example

Comment: Nice! I it worked for the scope examples :) but for some reason it breaks on my edit, but I can probably debug it and find out why :) Didn't really know I could use scopes like this, so thank you :)

Comment: Everything in javascript is an object. Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look on that :)